# GMail Api Use with iOS

Tags: ios, gmail-api

Is it legal possible to publish an app on the Apple Store that redirects to the Google Login Page to use an in-app functionality like the Gmail API ?

There have been various questions showing rejection of their apps from Apple Store due the rule mentioned under their developer guidelines as :

> 11.13 Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

So is it possible to use Google APIs which require login to a Google Account with iOS apps ?

Comment: In your case, you did not have "purchases" or "subscriptions"

Comment: @Raptor The Gmail Api allows users to add new accounts while authentication which according to Apple is considered to be a new subscription which may lead to purchases

Comment: Many Apps login with Gmail API. No worry for login part.